# Process of moving hotfixes to features and master branch

Tags: git

We had a hotfix for production - but I rebased it first with our staging environment as there were conflicts with staging. Our staging has some feature branches that are due to go into production next week.

Now, our hotfix since it got rebased has changes(features) that are in staging but are not due to go to production.

A) how can I move my hotfix to prod now?
B) how should I have initially handled the above scenario

Comment: (B) Your hotfixes should be staged in a copy of the production environment, then backported into dev/staging once deployed.

Answer (score 0):

The simple rule here is to test the code that you're planning to deploy, not some other combination of branches. Otherwise, there could be a bug in production that didn't show up in staging because of unreleased changes.

That means basing your hotfix on the code that's in production, and deploying it somewhere to test. If you only have one staging environment, that means pausing testing of new features there, and deploying your new branch instead.

This is *even more important* if there are conflicts with the features that are in staging, because that means they've touched the same parts of the application. The way you resolve those conflicts also needs to be tested, but that should happen *after* the hotfix is released, by merging the changes from the production branch into the branch that's due for release next week.

Comment: So I should have merged the hotfix first to production. Rebased staging with production? Is that what you mean. 

Anyway, to fix the problem I created?

Comment: The fix is just to rebase the branch onto production where it should have been in the first place. I would recommend merging the production branch to the staging one rather than rebasing it, otherwise you'll have to also rebase everything that's based on it, but that's obviously up to you. I would recommend you read up on some general advice on git workflows and having a clear policy in advance.